# Kohana 3 Admin Structure

Tags: structure, admin, kohana-3

I've been creating my admin backend of the site as another application, like so:

```
admin
--classes
----controller
----model
--views
--.htaccess
--bootstrap.php
--index.php

application
--classes
----controller
----model
--views
--bootstrap.php

.htaccess
index.php
```

But it's a bit annoying for me this way so I was thinking of just going back and placing the admin folder as a subfolder of the main application, which would usually be like this:

```
application
--classes
----controller
------admin
----model
------admin
--views
----admin
--bootstrap.php
.htaccess
index.php
```

I'm not too fond of this setup either though lol. So my question is, is it possible to create a structure like this?

```
application
--admin
----classes
------controller
------model
----views
--classes
----controller
----model
--views
--bootstrap.php
.htaccess
index.php
```

If that is not possible I guess I will just stick with the 2nd way. Although I have one more question, is it possible to move the controller and model folders above the classes? I'm sure there is a good reason for that setup? But honestly it just makes me have to click more to get there. I would prefer controller, model and views all in the same level, would that be possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can set `$application = 'application/admin'` in your admin's `index.php`.
2. Kohana's autoloader has hard-coded 'classes' directory for class files, so you cant move your classes without changing `Kohana::autoload()` method. Another (ugly) way is using symlinks.

Comment: Doesn't that set admin as a separate application? The reason I wanted to avoid using two applications is due to the extra index, bootstrap, etc. files. As well as trying to get the base url of the main application inside the admin app. I'll try this out and see if that happens.

Comment: I will just stick with the 2nd way for now, but thanks for your answer.